# if an override method returns something, what that means , how this can be Usefull?

Tags: java

What helps me if I make an interface. Then implement it on the class which will  override a method that returns a variable(e.g String,int,boolean).
What is the use of it ??

```
interface Animal {
        public boolean canBite();
}
```

//Now Implementing it on the class.

```
class Dog implements Animal {
  @Override
  public boolean canBite() {
     //do something here and return true or false
  }
```

}

Comment: class Duck implements Animal{
@Override
Public boolean canBite(){
   return false
 } 
}

Comment: #Andrew21111  duck class returning false, generally class have the something that is false. what is the Use of it. can you give the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces let you define methods that will be common to a group of classes. The implementation of the interface can be different for each class, and it's up to those classes to independently implement what that methods do.

```
interface Animal {
    // Define the interface
    Boolean canBite();
}

class Dog implements Animal {
    // Define an implementation for Dog
    @override
    public Boolean canBite() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Duck implements Animal {
    // Define an implementation for Duck
    @override
    public Boolean canBite() {
        return false;
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an array of the interface type and populate it with examples
        Animal[] animals = new Animal[4];
        animals[0] = new Dog();
        animals[1] = new Duck();
        animals[2] = new Duck();
        animals[3] = new Dog();

        // Check which members can bite
        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            System.out.println(animal.canBite());
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Output:
 * true
 * false
 * false
 * true
 */
```

Comment: In Duck Class Overrided method returning the false to class ???? if i don't make the Object of class, then what is the use of this method?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you give me more detail? If you don't make an Object (instance) of a class then you can't access the methods. Static methods are accessed from the class but instance methods are accessed from the Object.

Comment: duck class returning the the boolean value , Right ?   i can use that boolean value where i make the object of the class?? right ?? as you give the example , printing the value .

Comment: That's correct, Duck class returns false when the type is Animal because you created a Duck.

Answer (score 2):

Every class which will implement this interface and will also implement this method will return a different value. As a result you will have a different implementation of a method for a variaty of classes. In this way you can return the desire result to the method which called this method. Also this can help you if you have an abstract class you want to override this method and return your result back to the method which called it.